# When adding a new item to a list all other list values are being updated

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a list of dictionaries which should be very simple.  My code will add a new item correctly, but it will also update all other rows that were already in the list to the same value.  What am I missing?

```
while y < search_repo_count:
                search_repo_name = search_results[n]["items"][y]["repository"]["name"]

                if team_repo_name == search_repo_name:
                    print("Search Repo Name: " + search_repo_name + " Team Repo Name: " + team_repo_name + " y: " + str(y) + " z: " + str(z))
                    search_match["repo_name"] = search_repo_name
                    search_match["repo_url"] = search_results[n]["items"][y]["repository"]["html_url"]
                    search_match["result_url"] = search_results[n]["items"][y]["html_url"]

                    print(search_match)  **# This works as expected**

                    final_output.append(search_match)  **# This inserts a new record matching search_match as expected, but also updates all other rows to search_match as well.**  

                    print(final_output)
                    z = z + 1
                else:
                    print("No Match")

                y = y + 1
```

Results:
repo_abc is inserted into final_output as expected
repo_def is a new search value and is inserted as expected, however the prior value is also overwritten to the same new search value.  I would expect the first value to stay the same and just the new value added as a new record in the list.

```
Search Repo Name: repo_abc Team Repo Name: repo_abc y: 7 z: 1
{'repo_name': 'repo_abc', 'repo_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_abc', 'result_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_abc/blob/f7bd013c7d72136dfb70a7ed4ae07a947768e0bd/src/main/java/com/aexp/team-a/nmi/NMICalculator.scala'}
[{'repo_name': 'repo_abc', 'repo_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_abc', 'result_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_abc/blob/f7bd013c7d72136dfb70a7ed4ae07a947768e0bd/src/main/java/com/aexp/team-a/nmi/NMICalculator.scala'}, {'repo_name': 'repo_abc', 'repo_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_abc', 'result_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_abc/blob/f7bd013c7d72136dfb70a7ed4ae07a947768e0bd/src/main/java/com/aexp/team-a/nmi/NMICalculator.scala'}]
...
Search Repo Name: repo_def Team Repo Name: repo_def y: 11 z: 2
{'repo_name': 'repo_def', 'repo_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def', 'result_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def/blob/58769c59d6c1af2457b43dfaaf21c4ba2fb22594/ob-crmd-myca/scripts/myca_ob_ext.sh'}
[{'repo_name': 'repo_def', 'repo_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def', 'result_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def/blob/58769c59d6c1af2457b43dfaaf21c4ba2fb22594/ob-crmd-myca/scripts/myca_ob_ext.sh'}, {'repo_name': 'repo_def', 'repo_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def', 'result_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def/blob/58769c59d6c1af2457b43dfaaf21c4ba2fb22594/ob-crmd-myca/scripts/myca_ob_ext.sh'}, {'repo_name': 'repo_def', 'repo_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def', 'result_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def/blob/58769c59d6c1af2457b43dfaaf21c4ba2fb22594/ob-crmd-myca/scripts/myca_ob_ext.sh'}]

Search Repo Name: repo_def Team Repo Name: repo_def y: 12 z: 3
{'repo_name': 'repo_def', 'repo_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def', 'result_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def/blob/58769c59d6c1af2457b43dfaaf21c4ba2fb22594/ob-crmd-myca/scripts/myca_ob_ext.sh_org'}
[{'repo_name': 'repo_def', 'repo_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def', 'result_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def/blob/58769c59d6c1af2457b43dfaaf21c4ba2fb22594/ob-crmd-myca/scripts/myca_ob_ext.sh_org'}, {'repo_name': 'repo_def', 'repo_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def', 'result_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def/blob/58769c59d6c1af2457b43dfaaf21c4ba2fb22594/ob-crmd-myca/scripts/myca_ob_ext.sh_org'}, {'repo_name': 'repo_def', 'repo_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def', 'result_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def/blob/58769c59d6c1af2457b43dfaaf21c4ba2fb22594/ob-crmd-myca/scripts/myca_ob_ext.sh_org'}, {'repo_name': 'repo_def', 'repo_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def', 'result_url': 'https://github.aexp.com/this-org/repo_def/blob/58769c59d6c1af2457b43dfaaf21c4ba2fb22594/ob-crmd-myca/scripts/myca_ob_ext.sh_org'}]
```

In addition to the code above, I have tried to update final_output using `final_output[z] = search_match` and `final_output.insert(n, search_match)` but they all act the same.  I've also tried with final_output as a dictionary, but it has the same effect.

Comment: You need to create a new `search_match` dict for every match.  Currently, you're appending the *same* dict to `final_output` each time.

Comment: @jasonharper I know I'm using the same `search_match` but the values are successfully updated each time through.  I don't understand why the single value from `search_match` is updating all rows in `final_output` instead of just adding a new record.  I even added `search_match.clear()` before it loops and the behavior is the same

Comment: Appending `search_match` to the list *doesn't copy it* - any subsequent changes to the dict are just as visible in the list as in the dict itself.  And appending it multiple times just means multiple ways to see the same values.  You need a separate dict for each set of values, either by creating a new dict on each iteration as I had suggested, or appending a copy of the dict instead of the dict itself.

Comment: @jasonharper I got what you're saying now.  Thanks for the extended explanation.  When writing into final_output I'm now writing a copy of the search_match. Now it works as I wanted.  `final_output.append(search_match.copy())`